# Python 2.7.13 using openpyxl - error when accessing cells

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

Apologies, if this seems like a naive question.  I am a beginner and trying to use Python to automate some excel processes.  When using the below command to access cells in my spreadsheet I am getting an error which I cannot understand.

```
import openpyxl
excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('H:\sample.xlsx')
sheet = excel_document.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print(sheet('A2').value)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/Operations/PythonCode/hellopython.py/hellopython.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(sheet('A2').value)
TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what a callable is? If not please consult the Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
print(sheet('A2').value)
```

with

```
print(sheet['A2'].value)
```

(it's an index, not a function parameter).